# Disfunctionality of type parameter

Tags: scala

I’m new to using Scala and am trying to see if a list contains any objects of a certain type.

When I make a method to do this, I get the following results:

```
var l = List("Some string", 3)
def containsType[T] = l.exists(_.isInstanceOf[T])
containsType[Boolean]   // val res0: Boolean = true
l.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Boolean])   // val res1: Boolean = false
```

Could someone please help me understand why my method doesn’t return the same results as the expression on the last line?

Thank you,
Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scala uses the type erasure model of generics. This means that no
> information about type arguments is kept at runtime, so there's no way
> to determine at runtime the specific type arguments of the given
> `List` object. All the system can do is determine that a value is a
> `List` of some arbitrary type parameters.

You can verify this behavior by trying any `List` concrete type:

```
  val l = List("Some string", 3)

  println(l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]])       // true
  println(l.isInstanceOf[List[String]])    // true
  println(l.isInstanceOf[List[Boolean]])   // also true
  println(l.isInstanceOf[List[Unit]])      // also true
```

Now regarding your example:

```
  def containsType[T] = l.exists(_.isInstanceOf[T])
 
  println(containsType[Int])        // true
  println(containsType[Boolean])    // also true
  println(containsType[Unit])       // also true
  println(containsType[Double])     // also true
```

`isInstanceOf` is a synthetic function (a function generated by the Scala compiler at compile-time, usually to work around the underlying JVM limitations) and does not work the way you would expect with generic type arguments like `T`, because after compilation, this would normally be equivalent in Java to `instanceof T` which, by the way - is illegal in Java.

Why is illegal? Because of type erasure. Type erasure means all your generic code (generic classes, generic methods, etc.) is converted to non-generic code. This usually means [3 things](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

1. all type parameters in generic types are replaced with their bounds or `Object` if they are unbounded;
2. wherever necessary the compiler inserts type casts to preserve type-safety;
3. bridge methods are generated if needed to preserve polymorphism of all generic methods.

However, in the case of `instanceof T`, the JVM cannot differentiate between types of `T` at execution time, so this makes no sense. The type used with `instanceof` has to be *reifiable*, meaning that all information about the type needs to be available at runtime. This property does not apply to generic types.

So if Java forbids this because it can't work, why does Scala even allows it? The Scala compiler is indeed more permissive here, but for one good reason; because it treats it differently. Like the Java compiler, the Scala compiler also erases all generic code at compile-time, but since `isInstanceOf` is a synthetic function in Scala, calls to it using generic type arguments such as `isInstanceOf[T]` are replaced during compilation with `instanceof Object`.

Here's a sample of your code decompiled:

```
public <T> boolean containsType() {
    return this.l().exists(x$1 -> BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean(x$1 instanceof Object));
}

Main$.l = (List<Object>)package$.MODULE$.List().apply((Seq)ScalaRunTime$.MODULE$.wrapIntArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Predef$.MODULE$.println((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean(this.containsType()));
Predef$.MODULE$.println((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean(this.containsType()));
```

This is why no matter what type you give to the polymorphic function `containsType`, it will always result in `true`. Basically, `containsType[T]` is equivalent to `containsType[_]` from Scala's perspective - which actually makes sense because a generic type `T`, without any upper bounds, is just a placeholder for type `Any` in Scala. Because Scala cannot have raw types, you cannot for example, create a `List` without providing a type parameter, so every `List` must be a `List` of "something", and that "something" is at least an `Any`, if not given a more specific type.

Therefore, `isInstanceOf` can only be called with specific (concrete) type arguments like `Boolean`, `Double`, `String`, etc. That is why, this works as expected:

```
  println(l.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Boolean]))   // false
```

We said that Scala is more permissive, but that does not mean you get away without a warning.
To alert you of the possibly non-intuitive runtime behavior, the Scala compiler does usually emit unchecked warnings. For example, if you had run your code in the Scala interpreter (or compile it using `scalac`), you would have received this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to explain the problem to me, I've learned a lot today but am still trying to get my head around it. Really appreciate your kind help!

Kind regards,
Johan

Answer (score 3):

Alin's answer details perfectly why the generic isn't available at runtime. You can get a bit closer to what you want with the magic of [`ClassTag`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html), but you still have to be conscious of some issues with Java generics.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

var l = List("Some string", 3)

def containsType[T](implicit cls: ClassTag[T]): Boolean = {
  l.exists(cls.runtimeClass.isInstance(_))
}
```

Now, whenever you call `containsType`, a hidden extra argument of type `ClassTag[T]` gets passed it. So when you write, for instance, `println(containsType[String])`, then this gets compiled to

```
scala.this.Predef.println($anon.this.containsType[String](ClassTag.apply[String](classOf[java.lang.String])))
```

An extra argument gets passed to `containsType`, namely `ClassTag.apply[String](classOf[java.lang.String])`. That's a really long winded way of explicitly passing a `Class<String>`, which is what you'd have to do in Java manually. And `java.lang.Class` has an [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) function.

Now, this will mostly work, but there are still major caveats. Generics *arguments* are completely erased at runtime, so this won't help you distinguish between an `Option[Int]` and an `Option[String]` in your list, for instance. As far as the JVM is concerned, they're both `Option`.

Second, Java has an unfortunate history with primitive types, so `containsType[Int]` will actually be false in your case, despite the fact that the `3` in your list is *actually* an `Int`. This is because, in Java, generics can only be *class* types, not primitives, so a generic `List` can never contain `int` (note the lowercase 'i', this is considered a fundamentally different thing in Java than a class).

Scala paints over a lot of these low-level details, but the cracks show through in situations like this. Scala sees that you're constructing a list of `String`s and `Int`s, so it wants to construct a list of the common supertype of the two, which is `Any` (strings and ints have no common supertype more specific than `Any`). At runtime, Scala `Int` can translate to either `int` (the primitive) or `Integer` (the object). Scala will favor the former for efficiency, but when storing in generic containers, it can't use a primitive type. So while *Scala* thinks that your list `l` contains a `String` and an `Int`, *Java* thinks that it contains a `String` and a `java.lang.Integer`. And to make things even crazier, both `int` and `java.lang.Integer` have *distinct* `Class` instances.

So `summon[ClassTag[Int]]` in Scala is `java.lang.Integer.TYPE`, which is a `Class<Integer>` instance representing the primitive type `int` (yes, the non-class type `int` has a `Class` instance representing it). While `summon[ClassTag[java.lang.Integer]]` is `java.lang.Integer::class`, a distinct `Class<Integer>` representing the non-primitive type `Integer`. And at runtime, your list contains the latter.

In summary, generics in Java are a hot mess. Scala does its best to work with what it has, but when you start playing with reflection (which `ClassTag` does), you have to start thinking about these problems.

```
println(containsType[Boolean]) // false
println(containsType[Double])  // false
println(containsType[Int])     // false (list can't contain primitive type)
println(containsType[Integer]) // true  (3 is converted to an Integer)
println(containsType[String])  // true  (class type so it works the way you expect)
println(containsType[Unit])    // false
println(containsType[Long])    // false
```

Comment: Thank you for taking so much time to repond to me and explain everything in simpler terms. Really appreciate it and have a learned a lot from your post and Alin's today.

Kind regards,
Johan

Comment: If I had a superclass Animal and two sub-classes, Dog and Cat, what would then be the best way to create a function that can check if a list of Animals contains a Dog within it?

Comment: If using ClassTag is the only way and it only gives problems when using primitives, then that solution should work fine for me, since I'm just going to work on non-primitive classes, like the Cat and Dog ones.

I was just wondering if there's a better way and wanted to know if there could be unforseen consequences down the line if I use the ClassTag solution in a situation like the one with the Animals.